# Setting user access rules with access_control in controller methods for privacy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controllers

Currently I have given access control to two actions in my controller as:

```
access_control [:show, :index] => 'view_questions',

[:new, :create] => 'create_questions'
```

But now if I disable view questions user must still be able to create questions and view his own questions. How can I modify the access control settings so that if `'view_questions'` is disabled for the user, he can still view his questions?

I want to modify the action show in such a way that if `'view_questions'` is disabled, he must still be able to view his questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permission handling can very quickly get out of control when you try to roll own, especially if you're starting out. I'd highly recommend looking into something like CanCan:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan